# How to use the raft-rs crate and build with cargo?

Tags: rust, protocol-buffers, rust-cargo

I try to build the [single_mem_node example](https://github.com/tikv/raft-rs/tree/master/examples/single_mem_node), but as a standalone example and use the `raft-rs` crate as a library.

But unfortunately, I get this build error, when building using `cargo build`

```
error[E0599]: no method named `is_empty` found for reference `&raft_proto::protos::eraftpb::Snapshot` in the current scope
   --> src/main.rs:123:26
    |
123 |     if !ready.snapshot().is_empty() {
    |                          ^^^^^^^^ method not found in `&raft_proto::protos::eraftpb::Snapshot`
```

I have declared these dependencies in my `Cargo.toml`

```
[dependencies]
protobuf = { version = "2", features = ["with-bytes"] }
raft = "0.6.0-alpha"
slog = "2.5.2"
slog-term = "2.6.0"
slog-async = "2.5.0"
```

The instructions on how to use the `raft-rs` crate is:

> You can use raft with either rust-protobuf or Prost to encode/decode gRPC messages. We use rust-protobuf by default. To use Prost, build (or depend on) Raft using the prost-codec feature and without default features.

It certainly looks like I miss something around the `protobuf`... but what? and how do I find out about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the method was added [in this commit](https://github.com/tikv/raft-rs/commit/f145d5a9f4a6c59fd5165f3175356f94ea807055), after version `0.6.0-alpha` was released. GitHub shows the `master` branch by default, so in the future, try browsing at the commit that corresponds to the version you are using. In this case it is not tagged properly but I think [this commit is the published `0.6.0-alpha` version](https://github.com/tikv/raft-rs/commit/716e064627e8d900b674c4a508159850244cead6). In the example at that commit, [the corresponding line](https://github.com/tikv/raft-rs/blob/716e064627e8d900b674c4a508159850244cead6/examples/single_mem_node/main.rs#L135) is:

```rust
if !raft::is_empty_snap(ready.snapshot()) {
```

---

Alternatively, since it seems that `0.6.0-alpha` was released in July of 2019, if you want the latest changes on `master`, you could change the dependency in `Cargo.toml` to read:

```
raft = { git = "https://github.com/tikv/raft-rs" }
```

In that case, cargo will fetch the latest commit and store its hash in `Cargo.lock`, and you can update to a newer commit with `cargo update`.